# What was the name of the book about graduate students studying alien insects?

Tags: story-identification, novel

In the late 1960s I read a story about graduate students studying entomology going to a distant planet that was much like Earth but the insects that lived there were different. But they were nonetheless insects.

One of the students bore the first name "Kip". If I recall correctly, they stayed in the house of a woman who told them that insects of a certain species on that planet were "*a dime a dozen*" (i.e. very numerous). Each of them had a leave of absence from some university so they could make that trip, and that was where I first encountered the term "leave of absence".

Comment: Welcome to the site! You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: @Danny3414 : It was in the late '60s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The Space Plague* by A.M. Lightner

The [Kirkus review](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/am-lightner/the-space-plague/) mention class entomological field trip on planet Acoma.

Searching inside the [Google book](https://books.google.com/books?id=xxpUAAAAYAAJ) there's Kip.